# When calling a method IOException Error appears

Tags: java, exception, file-io

I am trying to write to a file.

I have declared an exception in the method writeHtmlFile, but the error "unreported exception java.io.IOException must be caught or declared to be thrown" keeps appearing anyway when I try to call on the writeHtmlFile method?

```
public class PartB extends ChangeDrawer
{

  public static ChangeDrawer cd = new ChangeDrawer();
  static int[] floatDrawer = {8,5,4,4,5,20,20,6,10,3,8};

   {
      String selection="";
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 

      System.out.println ("Enter P to make a purchase and receive your change");
      System.out.println ("Enter L to load the Change drawer");
      System.out.println ("Enter H to write the contents of the Change Drawer to a web page");
      System.out.println ("Enter E to exit the program");


    while (selection.compareTo("E")!=0)
    {
      selection = scan.next();
      if (selection.compareTo("P")== 0)
         makeChange();
      else if (selection.compareTo("L")==0)
         loadFloat();
       else if (selection.compareTo("H")==0)
         writeHtmlFile(); //unreported exception java.io.IOException must be caught or
                          //declared to be thrown


    }
        System.out.println ("Ending .............................. ");
    }


    //more code exists between these two sets

   public static void writeHtmlFile() throws IOException
   {
    FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("ChangeDrawer.html");
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
    outputFile.println("This should work!");

  }
```

Comment: Are you importing the correct IOException?

Comment: Ok. Reading Keith Randall's answer below I see now that I misunderstood the question. I think Keith's answer will help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that *calls* `writeHtmlFile` must catch (or redeclare to be thrown) the `IOException`.  Since the calling code is in a static initializer, it must be the former.

Comment: Throwing the exception where the code calls the writeHtmlFile method results in an "illegal expression" error

Comment: Indeed.  You cannot throw a (checked) exception from inside a static initializer.  You *must* catch it.  Use a `try/catch` block around the call.  Better yet, don't make this a static initializer, make it a method, like `main`.  Then you can just declare it to throw `IOException` and be done with it.